# Query accounts with filters

Tags: web3.js, anchor-client

I can get all accounts of a program via the following code with `@project-serum/anchor` JS library:

```
import * as anchor from "@project-serum/anchor";
import { Program } from "@project-serum/anchor";
import { MyProgram } from "../target/types/my_program";

const program = anchor.workspace.MyProgram as Program<MyProgram>;

const accounts = await program.account.myAccount.all();
```

According to the documentation, this function (`all`) has an optional filter parameter:

```
  /**
   * Returns all instances of this account type for the program.
   *
   * @param filters User-provided filters to narrow the results from `connection.getProgramAccounts`.
   *
   *                When filters are not defined this method returns all
   *                the account instances.
   *
   *                When filters are of type `Buffer`, the filters are appended
   *                after the discriminator.
   *
   *                When filters are of type `GetProgramAccountsFilter[]`,
   *                filters are appended after the discriminator filter.
   */
```

I am looking for an example on how such a filter can be created. For example, the data structure of the accounts in my example has a field `authority` which is a public key. I would like to apply a filter that only matches the accounts that have a certain public key as their authority.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an example usage of the `memcmp` filter in the [anchor repo](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/698426033052781988cd7980249726501ae08bdc/tests/misc/tests/misc/misc.ts#L820-L829)

- `offset` is 8 bytes (for the discriminator) + whatever other bytes come before the public key you're looking to filter based on.
- `bytes` is your public key converted to base58 bytes

```
    const allAccountsFilteredByProgramFilters1 =
      await program.account.dataWithFilter.all([
        {
          memcmp: {
            offset: 8,
            bytes: provider.wallet.publicKey.toBase58(),
          },
        },
      ]);
```